# Angular: If / else statement in view's Form

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm a total newbie with this "thing". I'm dealing with not mine code…

I have a view that has:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitCreateForm()">
```

I also have a variable I can use, called `type` that has either value `add` or `edit`.

How have 2 method defined `submitCreateForm` and `submitUpdateForm`

How can I modify the ngSubmit in the `<form>` to call `submitCreateForm` if type is `add` or `submitUpdateForm` when type is `edit`?

I know it sounds trivial, but the syntax is quite convoluted for me. Ideally I'm looking for a single line conditional.

Comment: Why don't you have `(ngSubmit)="submit()"` and in the component typescript have to logic call the respective method based on the `type` variable?

Comment: This makes sense. Please make your comment an aswer, I will upvote.

Comment: I would normally do this logic in a service based on if the object has a id or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you have `(ngSubmit)="submit()"` and in the component typescript have to logic call the respective method based on the type variable?

Comment: You comment was first and that makes sense to me as I don't want to pollute views. I defined generic submit and I pass type. This calls final method based on `type` value.

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator (?..:) for conditional rendering.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="type === 'add' ? submitCreateForm() : submitUpdateForm">
```

Answer (score 1):

In back end you can handle this you can call always submitForm()

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
```

let submitForm() function will decide which submit will call based  on type

```
 submitForm() 
 {
      if(this.type==="add"){
       this.submitCreateForm();
      }
      else{
       this.submitUpdateForm();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Ramesh (first comment under my question) was first with this solution. I will upvote both of you.

Comment: You get upvote as your solution is the same as Ramesh, but he was first for accepting answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is not the very good practice but this will do the trick. Try keeping two forms based on that Boolean.

```
<form ng-if="type == true" (ngSubmit)="submitCreateForm()">
<form ng-if="type != true" (ngSubmit)="submitUpdateForm()">
```

2) My second suggestion is use common submit action and separate logic based on the boolean 'type'